# Database relation many to many

Tags: database, many-to-many, relational

[alt text http://produits-lemieux.com/database.jpg](http://produits-lemieux.com/database.jpg)

This is basicly my database structure

one product (let say soap) will have many retail selling size

- 1 liter
- 4 liters
- 20 liters

In my "produit" database I will have the soap item (id #1)
In the size database i will have many size availible :

- 1liter
- 4liter
- 20liter

How not to duplicate the product 3 time with a different size... i like to be able to have check box in the product size of all the size available in the database and check if yes or no (boolean)

---

The answer a got is perfect, but how to have the option like that :

soap [x] 1 liter , [ ] 4 liter , [x] 20 liter

Comment: Just do the same as you are doing for formats, certifications and odeurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your exact scenario, but to create a many-to-many relationship, you simply create a "relationship table", in which you store id's for the two records you want to link.

Example:

```
Products
********
ProductID (PK)
Price

Retailers
*********
RetailerID (PK)
Name

ProductRetailerRelationships
****************************
ProductID
RetailerID
```

Comment: Darnit!  Another person sumits the right answer right as I start typing!

Comment: it is another database to maintain... is the checkbox option possible ?... but i totally understand you answer, and it work !

Comment: Also known as a cross-reference table or xref table for short.

Comment: It's technically not another *database* to maintain - just another *table* in the same DB. This technique is very common, and is usually one of the first recommendations when talking about *normalizing* databases - that is, making sure that each piece of information is only saved in one place. You *can* do what you want with checkboxes, but you will have to save the same data in several places, thus making it much harder to make sure that you don't have conflicting data.

Comment: Another question, is it still pertinent to have the relationship  (foreing key) beetween product and format, if i will go with the join database (table)

Comment: This layout is only for *many*-to-*many* relationships - if one product can only be of one format, your current approach is good enough. However, if one product row should be able to correspond to several formats, you probably want to implement a `ProductFormatRelationships` table as well.

Answer (score 0):

A many-to-many relationship is almost always modeled using an intermediate table. For your example,

```
Product
--------
prod_numero
...

Size
--------
size_numero
...

Product_Size
--------
prod_numero
size_numero
...
```

The `Size` table would contain particular sizes (say, 10 liter) and the `Product_Size` table creates a `Product` and `Size` pairing.

Answer (score 0):

You Will need an Intermediary, or "Join" Table

ProductSizes
.......................
ProductID
SizeID

One record for each product-size combination

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answers, here is the database tables layout as proposed, it look complicated to me, but are you sure it is the way to do this, the BEST solution ?

[alt text http://produits-lemieux.com/database2.jpg](http://produits-lemieux.com/database2.jpg)

Comment: I start to think, maybe to go with a xml structure... But i can remember i have read somewhere : Once upon a time, a programmer have a problem, then he use xml, now he have two problem !...